# Temporarily #undef macros when using #import directive for importing COM typelib

Tags: com, typelib

I'm trying to use a COM library in C++. I've got a #import "TheLibrary.dll" and it creates the tlh and tli files with the classes in the library.

Now, my problem is that the COM object exposes a few enums with the values of some lists of constants that are also in the Windows SDK headers. I presume this is so that Visual Basic developers have named variants of these constants, rather than having to use their numeric values.

But this poses a problem for me, as these headers are included before my typelib is #import'ed; so now the enum member declarations are being replaced with the numeric constants in the windows header files, causing my compilation to fail.

Example:

windows header file:

```
#define RES_AND ((ULONG) 0x00000000)
```

generated tlh:

```
enum __declspec(uuid(-some guid-))
RestrictionKind
{
    RES_AND = 0,
.. etc
```

So the problem is obvious; the enum in the tlh is expanded, and the result is an attempt to assign a constant to a number.

Now I see several solutions, all of them unattractive:

- do a 'rename' on each item, at the time of the #import. There are hundreds of these constants, not looking forward to that.
- leave out the enums all together. That would cripple my access to the COM object seriously (I haven't tried this out yet, maybe the whole library will even become unusable).
- do a #undef of all these constants before the #import. Again, there are hundreds of them, and on top of that I wouldn't be able to use them afterward - unless I do a #define again...

So I'm kind of at a loss here. I'm hoping for a way to do mass renames of enum values, but the documentation on the #import directive isn't giving me much hope.

Any ideas amongst the few remaining COM programmers out there? Thanks.

Comment: You exaggerate, no doubt.  Getting hundreds of macro name collisions just doesn't happen.  Just #undef them.  Give up on COM when you get more than a dozen.

Comment: I just wrote a script to generate the rename() entries from the compiler warnings. There were 834 conflicts. I got it to compile now, all seems to be OK. Giving up on this component is not an option (well in programming anything is always an option - let's say 'giving up on this component would require me to duplicate 5 years of work, testing and working around the bugs in another, unrelated app that this COM component interfaces with').

Comment: Also, FWIW the script took me 10 minutes so looking back it would've been faster if I had just done that from the beginning. Ah well, the benefits of hindsight...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have three options.

Option 1. If you can change that component interface - do that, rename the enum values so that they don't conflict with Windows SDK.

Option 2. Use `#import` with `rename`. Although you have hundreds of those elements you can build a nice table splitting the list with use of backslashes.

Option 3. Try to isolate the `#import` into a separate .h file so that either isn't included with all the Windows SDK or at least is imported with a much smaller number of files. This will eliminate or reduce conflicts and then you can use `rename` for the remaining conflicts.

Comment: Thanks. It's someone else's component so I can't change it. I guess I'll have to write a script to generate the 'rename' list from the compiler warnings output. Bleh. Ah well.